# Git push to Heroku never pass from Writing and Total objects message's step

Tags: git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm a web development student.
In the course, they teach using a free Heroku account.

Turns out I can't push to Heroku anymore.
When I try, I stop at the beginning, at the step shown below:

```
sssv-721 git:(master) git push heroku master -v
  Pushing to https://git.heroku.com/sssv-721.git
  Enumerating objects: 188, done.
  Counting objects: 100% (187/187), done.
  Delta compression using up to 4 threads
  Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (154/154), 2.10 MiB | 102.40 MiB/s, done.
  Total 154 (delta 95), reused 151 (delta 94)
  POST git-receive-pack (2202066 bytes)
```

It just doesn't get past that step.

There are no pending commits.
I've already restarted the computer.
I've already deleted the project folder and made a git clone of the app straight from Heroku.
I've already tried doing a git push from different branches.
Nothing did work.

The strange thing is that push to github works perfectly.

I'm using `Ubuntu v20.04.3 LTS`, `Rails v6.0.4.1`, `Git v2.25.1` and `Heroku CLI v7.59.1`.

I appreciate any help.